# Cassandra solr_query not working after upgrading to DSE 5

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cqlsh, datastax-php-driver

After upgrading to `DSE 5 solr_query` is not working. Below is the new DSE, cqlsh and Cassandra versions.

> [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.7.1158 | DSE 5.0.0 | CQL spec 3.4.0 |
>   Native protocol v4]

I am connecting using PHP Driver. The exception catching is

> Must not send frame with CUSTOM_PAYLOAD flag for native protocol
>   version < 4

and the

> error code is 33554442

When I run the same query on cqlsh it is working but not through the Php-driver.

```
$countSearchParam = '{"q":"'.$searchParam.'" }';
try{
$countStatement = $this->session->prepare(
                "SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE solr_query = ? ");
                $countresults = $this->session->execute($countStatement, new Cassandra\ExecutionOptions(array(
                'arguments' => array($countSearchParam)
                )));

                foreach ($countresults as $row) {
                    $cntArr = get_object_vars($row['count']);
                    $totCount = $cntArr['value'];                
                }
}catch(Exception $e){

}
```

Comment: Whats the query and php code?

Comment: @phact: I have edited my question and added the code

Answer (score 1):

PHP driver v1.1 does not support native protocol v4; however v1.2 is in the testing stages of development and will support v4 along with new features introduced in Cassandra v2.2 and v3.x. A version with specific DSE 5.0 features will begin after PHP driver v1.2 is released.

You can follow v1.2 release [here](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?rapidView=21&quickFilter=323).